# Constructor not CLS-compliant with TimeSpan argument and inheriting Attribute

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, timespan, cls-compliant

Ok I'm stumped: why is a class not CLS-compliant when its only constructor has a `System.TimeSpan` argument **and** the class inherits from `System.Attribute`?

Here's a min-repro, plus proof that both `System.Attribute` and `System.TimeSpan` *are* CLS-compliant:

```
using System;

[assembly:CLSCompliant(true)]

namespace Test
{
    public class CLSCompliantClass1
    {
        public TimeSpan Foo; // CLS-compliant
        public CLSCompliantClass1(TimeSpan bar) { } // CLS-compliant
    }

    public class CLSCompliantClass2 : Attribute
    {
        public TimeSpan Foo; // CLS-compliant
        public CLSCompliantClass2(double foo) { } // CLS-compliant
    }

    public class NonCLSCompliantClass : Attribute
    {
        // 'Test.NonCLSCompliantClass' has no accessible constructors which use only CLS-compliant types
        public NonCLSCompliantClass(TimeSpan bar) { } // not CLS-compliant??
    }
}
```

To compile run:

```
>csc /t:library cls.cs /warnaserror /nologo
cls.cs(19,15): error CS3015: Warning as Error: 'Test.NonCLSCompliantClass' has no accessible constructors which use only CLS-compliant types
```

(repros with any `/langversion:1..5`)

Comment: Just try to actually use the attribute and it will be pretty obvious.

Comment: @HansPassant, very good point, however I disagree with "pretty obvious". Declaring an attribute with a `TimeSpan` arg yields `error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression...` - why does that render the attribute class as non-CLS-compliant?

Comment: Well, if you can't use the attribute in C# then you are not going to have much luck in another language either.  The values you pass to the attribute constructor are stored in the metadata of the assembly.  The CLS spec dictates what kind of values are legal.   It is a short list, CLS rule #34 only allows string, char, bool, byte, short, int, long, float, double, enum and Type.  Chapter I.9.7 in Ecma-335.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for citing the rule, given that I'll accept "pretty obvious" :). Though an attribute class *can* be used beyond attribute declarations: e.g. I initially ran into this when implementing a `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` (WebAPI) which is often used as `config.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttributeImpl(TimeSpan.Zero))`. (Leaving the merits of this pattern outside the scope of this discussion.)